# Tooltip overriding the text in chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I have created a graph like below using `chart.js`

[image]

The above graph the texts like (Bare, Mounted) I creates this in `oncomplete` function like

```
onComplete: function () {

    // render the value of the chart above the bar
    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.chart.config.options.defaultFontColor;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
            var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
            if(dataset._meta[0].controller.index==1){
                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x-10, model.y+8);
                ctx.fillText('Mounted', model.x-25, model.y+38);
                ctx.fillText('360 (Available)', model.x-42, model.y-25);
            }else{
                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], 10, model.y+8);
                ctx.fillText('Bare', 12, model.y+38);
                ctx.fillText($scope.labels[i], 12, model.y-25);
            }

        }
    });
}}
```

But these values are rendered above the tooltip. How can I avoid this??

Comment: do you want the values(20, 40, 45) in bottom of tool tip?

Comment: No. See the pic. i don't want to overlap tooltip with text ( Mounted )

Comment: Then you can go css side. give z-index high for tooltip like 99999. if  mounted have z-index just change it low or remove it.

Comment: I think you know css very well. why didn't try z-index.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `onComplete` will be called at the end of the animation. That is how `onComplete` is supposed to work. If there is a tooltip to be drawn, `onComplete` will be called after the tooltip has been drawn, since drawing the tooltip is part of the animation. This is the reason that your texts are drawn above everything else. What you could do is create (and register) a plugin to draw your texts (ditch the `onComplete` approach). Look at the [docs about creating a plugin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins). You will have to override one method only (play around to find out which method to override, see some plugin examples, also pay attention to how `easing` is used) where you should be able to use your current code with just a few changes.

Comment: Great answer that helps understanding issue clearly. 
For my case, I change to `beforeDraw` and tooltip now "above" those text

Comment: Can you show your code please? I don't understand about structure. Thank you. #